# How to logged in to mongodb as admin?

Tags: database, mongodb, authentication, console, admin

I created admin:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.createUser(
...   {
...     user: 'admin',
...     pwd: 'password',
...     roles: [ { role: 'root', db: 'admin' } ]
...   }
... );
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "root",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ]
}
> exit;
```

But when I wanted to logged in I get an error:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.auth('admin','password');
Error: Authentication failed.
0
```

I tried also with:

```
mongo --port 27017  --authenticationDatabase "admin" -u "admin" -p "password"
```

and:

```
mongo localhost:27017/admin -u admin -p password
```

But it also doesn't work.

Comment: I tried the same code it works for me. Can you try the same in root user account?

Comment: Maybe a typo. Did you restart the mongod after you enabled authentication?

Comment: @Deepak velu What you mean to try the same in root user account? This admin that I created has root role

Comment: @Domscheit it cannot be a typo because I copied these commands from the console. To restart the mongod I used `db.adminCommand( { shutdown: 1 } )`, is it ok? To log in I have to enable authentication (this in mongo config file)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, of course `shutdown` only stops the mongod but does not start it again. How do you start the mongod? What do you get from `db.serverCmdLineOpts()`?

Comment: @Weronika What I meant was try this code in your admin account of your PC

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After restarting my PC, I was able to log in to mongodb as admin.